# Linux: File is not shown in ls but cannot be touched with message "File exists"

Tags: linux, filesystems, openvz, ext4, debian-wheezy

I can remember creating this file but it disapeard. But not completely:

```
root@XXX:/etc/vz/conf# ls -al
total 0
drwxr-x--- 2 root www-data 0 Okt  1 16:04 .
drwxr-x--- 2 root www-data 0 Okt  1 16:04 ..

root@XXX:/etc/vz/conf# touch 1030.conf
touch: cannot touch `1030.conf': File exists

root@warp1:/etc/vz/conf# echo blah > 1030.conf
-bash: 1030.conf: File exists

root@warp1:/etc/vz/conf# rm 1030.conf
rm: cannot remove `1030.conf': No such file or directory
```

System is Debian7 / Proxmox:

`Linux warp1 2.6.32-24-pve #1 SMP Fri Sep 13 07:29:30 CEST 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

What is causing this and how can I get my file back / get rid of it and how do I debug sth. like this? Thanks!

Comment: Try a quick `fsck` to have it cleared up.

Comment: Does `lsattr -d .` output anything else than `-` before the `.`?

Comment: `root@warp1:/etc/vz/conf# lsattr -d . lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on .`

Comment: `root@warp1:/etc/vz/conf# fsck.ext4 -n /dev/sdb2
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Warning!  /dev/sdb2 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
/dev/sdb2: clean, 62405/34643968 files, 2990165/138561792 blocks
`

Comment: it may be opened by another program, try searching with lsof | grep 1030.conf

Comment: Is /etc really on /dev/sdb2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file exists on another node in your cluster and Proxmox checks for that. You need to do something like:

```
mv /etc/pve/nodes/[node1]/openvz/whatever.conf /etc/pve/nodes/[node2]/openvz
```

to move the config to a different node.

Comment: Brilliant. I wasn't event aware that I'm running a cluster. Just wantet to use the proxmox kernel because debian 7 doesn't include openvz kernels anymore.

Comment: Looking at the directory you mentioned I see that the root of the problem seems to be that I've renamed my host and this was recognised as new node.

Comment: Do you know what to do if I don't want this feature or what exactly is doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything you can do to make it more like a single machine. But perhaps it's worthy of a separate question; I'm not really a proxmox expert!